# Conditional logic based on cpu load issue

Tags: bash

I'am developing bash script, which enabling/disabling ddos protection from cloudflare. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

PERC=$(grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat | awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} END {print usage}');

if [[ "$PERC" -gt 50 ]]
    then
        echo 'high load';
    else
        echo 'normal load';
fi
```

I have 2 issues:
1. PERC are always the same result
2. seems like result of PERC variable incorrect, because of error '-bash: [[: 41.8679: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".8679")'

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

Using point-in-time CPU load can lead to very misleading results – say you happen to catch it when it's in the middle of refreshing a cache which take 100% CPU for 0.2 seconds…

Furthermore `bash` can only handle integer arithmetic. You can use a tool like `bc` to do more complex operations. Alternatively, given you probably don't care about the decimal value, you could strip it off (`cut -d. -f 1`)

Have you considered using the long-established *load average* concept that's been in UNIX for a long time?

- https://superuser.com/questions/23498/what-does-load-average-mean-on-unix-linux
- https://www.howtogeek.com/194642/understanding-the-load-average-on-linux-and-other-unix-like-systems/

Also bear in mind that the arithmetic (despite not working) may not work on other platforms:

> /proc/stat
>                 kernel/system statistics.  Varies with architecture.  Common entries include:
>
> ```
>           cpu  3357 0 4313 1362393
>                  The amount of time, measured in  units  of  USER_HZ  (1/100ths  of  a  second  on  most  architectures,  use
>                  sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK) to obtain the right value), that the system spent in various states
> ```
>
> ...